# Trouble installing Windows 7 (64) or Server 2008 (64) on an Intel DH55TC i5 machine

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-server-2008, intel-core-i5

I have this Intel i5 (DH55TC mobo) machine that someone previously installed Windows 7 32 bit on.   It works fine, but I need more RAM, so I installed 10 Gigs but of course I need to install a 64bit OS to utilize it.

When I boot the Windows 7 64 Bit install DVD, it takes FOREVER at the various points - after loading files, it shows a black screen for probably 10-15 minutes then goes to the 'loading setup' -- I think I waited an hour before giving up.   I have tried a different DVD drive, different DVD media, unplugging EVERYTHING from the machine except the hard drive (sata 160gb) and the DVD rom.     I have even tried IDE Native mode (instead of AHCI).

I also tried Server 2008 64 bit.   Similar results.    Though I did manage once to get it to go all the way through and install.   However when it boots from the hard drive, it loads up to a black screen and does nothing - just sits there indefinitely.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing some of the RAM back to the original config when WIN732 functioned and trying again?  The manual indicates matched DIMMS.  Is that what you installed? 10GB is an unusual number.  [DH55TC Manual](http://downloadmirror.intel.com/18505/eng/DH55TC_ProductGuide01_English.pdf)

Comment: Yes, that did the trick, removing the other set of DIMMS.